# How can I automatically change directory on ssh login?

Tags: login, ssh

I'm trying to get `ssh` to automatically change to a particular directory when I log in. I tried to get that behaviour working using the following directives in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host example.net
LocalCommand "cd web"
```

but whenever I log in, I see the following:

```
/bin/bash: cd web: No such file or directory
```

although though there is definitely a `web` folder in my home directory. Even using an absolute path gives the same message. To be clear, if I type `cd web` after logging in I get to the right folder.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

Different combinations of quotes/absolute paths give different error messages:

```
LocalCommand "cd web"
/bin/bash: cd web: No such file or directory

LocalCommand cd web
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: web: No such file or directory

LocalCommand cd /home/gareth/web
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: /home/gareth/web: Input/output error
```

This makes me think that the quotes shouldn't be there, and that there's another error happening.

Comment: LocalCommand is run on your local system, not the remote system.

Comment: See here http://superuser.com/a/124110/47962

Answer (score 57, accepted):

<s>cd is a shell builtin.  LocalCommand is executed as:</s>

```
/bin/sh -c <localcommand>
```

What you're looking to do can't really be accomplished via SSH; you need to modify the shell in some way, e.g. via `bashrc/bash_profile`.

<Editing almost a decade later...>

`LocalCommand` isn't what you want, anyway. That's run on *your* machine.

You want `RemoteCommand`. Something like this worked for me:

```sh
Host example.net
  RemoteCommand cd / && exec bash --login
  RequestTTY yes
```

Comment: Yep, just wanted to mention to same. You can put the `cd` command in `~/.bashrc` at the remote server instead.

Comment: That's annoying. As I mentioned in another comment, the server has a number of hostnames and I wanted to have different behaviour based on which was used. I guess it's not possible to determine which was used from .bashrc?

Comment: It's possible, just probably not advisable.  Something like replacing ssh with a small shell script or alias that passes the host name as a variable to be exported (a la "ssh -t user@host 'export connhostname=host; bash --login'").  But you're starting to get into very strange territory, indeed.  Perhaps a better question is, WHY do you want this behavior?

Comment: It's not really that big a deal to be honest. I'm just in the situation where the vast majority of the time I log into this server I head straight to one of two directories (depending on which host I'm using)

Comment: What is `RequestTTY yes` for?

Comment: the exec bash --login part is awesome. Without that I get logged out immediately.

Comment: Works like a charm. Synology NAS / DSM uses the `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @reynoldsnlp Without `RequestTTY`, a `RemoteCommand` is assumed to be something that doesn't need a TTY (*cough*PTY*cough*) assigned.  A TTY gives remote programs (like your shell) the ability to move the cursor, set window title, use colors, etc.  Since you almost certainly want those things (using something like Bash or zsh without an assigned TTY is very, very annoying at best, if it works at all), we force our local `ssh` to request a TTY from the remote `sshd` via `RequestTTY yes`.

Answer (score 93):

This works:

```
ssh server -t "cd /my/remote/directory; bash --login"
```

To create a directory if it doesn't exist:

```
ssh server -t "mkdir -p newfolder; cd ~/newfolder; pwd; bash --login"
```

If you don't add `bash` to the end of path then you exit after the `cd` comand runs. And If you don't add `--login` then your `~/.profile` isn't sourced.

Comment: This ends me up at the correct location, with a bash prompt. perfect!

Comment: This works for me too but if I try to use it with ssh jump-host it doesn't work. I get a connection closed message.

Comment: This works perfectly for me.

Comment: You can also specify another shell if you want. For example, you can replace `bash` with `zsh`

Answer (score 69):

1. Login to your box
2. Edit `~/.bash_profile`
3. On the end of the file add `cd /path/to/your/destination`
4. Save it & exit
5. Logout from the box
6. Login again and then you should land on `/path/to/your/destination`

> *Note (Dec 2021): As @Matthias points out on some machines you may need need to append your command to `~/.bashrc` instead of to `~/.bash_profile`.*

Comment: On some machines you may need need to append `cd /path/to/your/destination` to `~/.bashrc` instead of to `~/.bash_profile`. The result should be the same.

Comment: This works perfectly thanks - is it only restricted to my user id or will it affect others user logins as well?

Comment: @BabyGroot if you modify `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` it will only affect the current user.

Comment: I noticed I had to use `.bashrc`, but apart from that it works great!

Comment: perfecto gracias

Answer (score 5):

Have you enabled this directive in your ssh config?

```
PermitLocalCommand yes
```

The default for that is `no`, in which case your `LocalCommand` directive would be ignored.

Alternatively, have you tried adding the command to your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: That directive is set, yes (and I assume I wouldn't see the error message shown if it wasn't). The problem with using .bashrc is that the server has different host names, and I'd like different host names to translate to different starting directories

Comment: Unless each host name has a different IP address, there would be no way for the server to know which host name you requested.  While HTTP requests provide a friendly Host: header to identify the requested host name, SSH connections do not.

Answer (score 4):

More robust solution for the case when you need to ssh and override default .bashrc file. This is useful in cases when remote server environment has multiple docroots and used by multiple users.

```
alias ssh_myserver='ssh server_name -t "echo cd /path/to/desired/dir>/tmp/.bashrc_tmp; bash --rcfile /tmp/.bashrc_tmp"'
```

More detailed:

1. First command creates `.bashrc_tmp` file in `/tmp` directory on the remote server with a content `cd /path/to/dir`
2. Next command executes `bash` with config file specified in step 1. This allows to switch to desired dir and suppress default `.bashrc`.
3. This whole command is wrapped as an `alias`, so on ssh client command prompt it can be called as `ssh_myserver`

Comment: Creative... as long as you have write perms to /tmp

Answer (score 4):

So I have searched a lot of websites (stackoverflow, this one) but did not find what I wanted. I ended up creating my own shell script. I am pasting it here. Also you can copy it a directory in the $PATH.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t <username@hostname> "cd ~/$1; exec \$SHELL --login"
```

So after this. I do:

```
connect <foldername>
```

Note: You may need to log out and log in again after changing the path variable

Comment: I prefer this to the previous suggestion because '$SHELL' is always valid, while 'bash' may not be.  Also the use of 'exec' is a nice touch.

Comment: A further refinement would to be ensure 'cd' is successful - "cd ~/$1 && exec ...'

Answer (score 3):

In your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
LocalCommand echo '/home/%r/some/subdir' > /home/%r/.ssh/ssh_cd
```

At the end of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [[ -f $HOME/.ssh/ssh_cd ]]
then
    cd $(<$HOME/.ssh/ssh_cd)
    # uncomment the line below and the file will be removed so the cd won't work
    # unless the file is regenerated since you may not want this to operate for
    # non-ssh logins or for ssh logins that you want to function differently
    # rm $HOME/.ssh/ssh_cd
fi
```

I tried doing this using variable passing, including with an exported variable, but these commands get run in different shells.

When testing what you were trying to do I didn't get an error when I used the unquoted absolute path, by the way. I added `; pwd` at the end of the command and the correct directory is displayed, however the directory I end up in is `~`. There are no `cd` commands in my shell startup files. I tried putting a different `cd somedir; pwd` in `~/.ssh/rc` (with the other still in place). The `config` command is executed before the motd is issued and the `rc` command is issued afterwards, but before the shell startup files are sourced. So again, it's happening in a different shell.

Try the passing-by-file technique and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it without the quotes around it? The only examples I've seen don't have them so with them it could be trying to execute cd\ web as a command.

Comment: Ok, removing quotes seem to help but I still have errors (see edited post)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this, with the option `-t`:

```
ssh server -t "cd /my/remote/directory; bash"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `RemoteCommand` instead, e.g.

```
Host myhost
  HostName IP
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  RemoteCommand cd web; $SHELL -il
```

> `RemoteCommand`: Specifies a command to execute on the remote machine after successfully connecting to the server. (`man ssh_config`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to create `~/.bash_profile` although you already have a `~/.bashrc`.

On my `debian` system the `~/.bashrc` was not executed upon login with `sshpass`.

Since I added `cd directory` to the newly created `~/.bash_profile` it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in `.ssh/config`:

```
  RemoteCommand cd ~/mydir;bash
  RequestTTY force
```