# SSH into Google Compute Engine using automated deployment (i.e., CircleCI)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to SSH into my Compute Engine instance using CircleCI with a command that looks like this in config.yml:

`gcloud --quiet compute ssh [INSTANCE_NAME] --zone northamerica-northeast1-a --project [PROJECT_NAME]
cd /var/www/dev`

I can successfully authenticate and see the command prompt in CircleCI logs. However, the commands after SSH are not being carried out. What am I doing wrong here?

```
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Sep 12 15:53:55 2018 from 18.212.180.159

[USER_NAME]:~$
```

I expect to have cd command run after successful authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SSH, it seems you cannot change directory by just passing the command, and this is an SSH limitation per this [Serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/167416/how-can-i-automatically-change-directory-on-ssh-login?answertab=active#tab-top). Generally, you can run an executable file using SSH by using `-c` flag, and similarly using [`--command`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--command) with gcloud like [this example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/gcloud$20ssh$20fady%7Csort:date/gce-discussion/VQ3UqgkxaE8/1uqoCXy-CAAJ).

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-east1-c test --command="nohup ping -i 5 google.com > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &"
```

However, from the above serverfault post it seems that changing directory can be acheived by using `-t` flag, in addition to executing several commands in one statement. Luckily gcloud can also make use of such flags by adding [`--ssh-flag`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--ssh-flag). Here is an example that changes directory and outputs the system path.

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-central1-c  instance-2 --ssh-flag="-t" --command="cd /bin; pwd"
/bin
Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.
```

Note that SSH exited (connection closed) once the last command `pwd` was executed. To stay logged in and as suggested in the post use `bash --login`

I am not sure in circleCI how commands are run, but in general to run a command in linux you can specify the full path directly, rather than changing directory. For example, `/some/directory/executablefile` will run the `executablefile`.